# Почему приходит пустой массив в print(test) dart?

Tags: dart, async-await, future

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:dio/dio.dart';

void main() async {
  var test = [];
  test = await start();
  print(test);
}

start() {
  List<int> ids = [1, 2, 3];
  List answer = [];
  ids.forEach((id) {
    var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/$id';
    var answer = query(url);
  });
  return answer;
}

query(url) async {
  List ans = [];
  var dio = Dio();
  final response = await dio.get(url);
  print(response.statusCode);
  Map data = response.data;
  data.entries.forEach((element) {
    ans.add(element.key);
    ans.add(element.value);
  });
  return ans;
}
```

Comment: Если ответ помог, то см: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), если нет - напишите комментарий или замечания

Answer (score 0):

Все просто

```
start() {
  List<int> ids = [1, 2, 3];
  // Вы объявляете пустой список
  List answer = [];
  // ...
  // Вы возвращаете пустой список
  return answer;
}
```

а здесь вы с этим списком **не взаимодействуете**

```
ids.forEach((id) {
    var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/$id';
    // здесь вы создаёте ЛОКАЛЬНУЮ ПЕРЕМЕННУЮ
    // которая никак не связана со списком уровнем выше
    var answer = query(url);
});
```

Чтобы все работало вам нужно

1. убрать объявление новой локальной переменной `var answer` в цикле
2. и не перезаписывать значение переменной `answer`
   как это происходило бы при 
   `answer = query(url)`
   а добавлять в нее новые элементы с помощью метода `add()`

Как-то так:

```
start() {
  List<int> ids = [1, 2, 3];
  List answer = [];
  ids.forEach((id) {
    var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/$id';
    answer.add(query(url));
  });
  return answer;
}
```